# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (XMPP library in Unity exported xcode

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, clang, xmppframework

I have export xCode from unity. Code is also work fine. But when I include XMPP library. xcode gives error like below

[image]

Below are the image for **Header path** and **Library path**

[image]

[image]

As you can see the last path in library is added when XMPP library is added. (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) If I remove this path then xcode gives below error.

[image]

I am not understanding what is the issue. For more debug porpes when I have created normal xcode project xcode has not given any error. That means when I have exported the code from unity there must be some path or setting create a problem.

Please anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is the same problem which i had faced during my connection @Crazy Developer make sure that you had import the library by "Podfile" after that it not get problem.